# Dataerror using pivot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I'm using the following command to `pivot` a bunch of rows:

```
df[df.branch=='ALG'].reset_index().pivot_table(index='branch', columns='monyear', values='conceptname')
```

The column `conceptname` is a `string` column and therefore I get the following error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

How do I get `pandas` to ignore this? I don't really want to aggregate anything, I just want to reshape my data in a columnar format.

Here's my input data:

```
branch    monyear    conceptname
A          Jul         text1
A          Jul         text2
A          Aug         text3
A          Aug         text4
B          Jul         text5
B          Jul         text6
B          Aug         text7
B          Aug         text8
```

Desired output:

```
branch    Jul    Aug
A        text1  text3
A        text2  text4
B        text5  text7
B        text6  text8
```

`A` and `B` can be thought of as different branches selling stuff in different months (`Jul` and `Aug`). I'd like to list the stuff sold by these branches in different months.

Any help would be appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: Can you add sample input data and your desired output?

Comment: If you just want to reshape your data you could use `df.transpose`? Or if I'm misinterpreting your ask. `df.pivot_table` is using a default `aggfunc` param as `mean` so you could write something as a substitute that accepts a string value (say for instance something similar to `first()`? i.e `aggfunc=lambda x: x[0]`

Comment: Also like @ayhan said it would help to know exactly what values you want your `conceptname` series to transform into.

Comment: Why is it not 1 4 and 2 3? What differentiates those A's?

Comment: I have added the input and desired output now.

Comment: @ayhan: Sorry I didn't get your question. Think of it as different branches selling stuff named text1, text2, text3, text4 in different Months. I would like to have these Months as columns.

Comment: I mean you have 4 branches named A. In the desired output, for the first row you expect text1 and text 3. My question is, why not text1 and text4? Because they seem to belong to the same branch.

Comment: I see. A's are all the same branch. They may sell different stuff in a given month. I'm trying to accumulate the top stuff they sell in a given month. so branch `A` may be selling 20 different things in `Jul` and another 20 different things in `Aug`. I'd like to list the top 20 from each month. I have the 20 in my `dataframe`, I only want to reshape it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df_ = df.set_index(['branch']).groupby('monyear').apply(lambda x: x.T).T

df_ = df_.xs('conceptname', axis=1, level=1)

print df_

monyear    Aug    Jul
branch               
A        text3  text1
A        text4  text2
```

Comment: Gives me `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works partly. It creates additional columns for like `Jul monyear`, `Jul conceptname`, `Aug monyear`, `Aug conceptname` etc. So for example, the two columns for `Jul` give me values of only `monyear` in one column and the value of `conceptname` in the other column. Is there a way I can get only the `conceptname` values in the column. Right now, I'll have to manually go ahead and delete the `monyear` column.

Comment: the second line takes care of this.  I've fixed the typo.

Comment: Awesome, that does it. Thanks a lot for your help. You also might want to include the `lambda` back in your answer so people looking at it in the future may get it completely.